# Why does only a part of the code execute on submission of a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a form which, on submitting, triggers the function "`validateForm()`" from an external `.js` file. Here's the html:

```
        <div class="loginContainer">
            <div id="login "class="login">
            <img src="picture.tiff" class="loginImage">
            <div class="loginHeading">
                Login
            </div>
            <form id="form" onsubmit="validateForm()">
                <input type="text" class="loginTextbox" name="name" placeholder="Username"></input>
                <input type="password" class="loginTextbox" name="password"  placeholder="Password"></input>
                <div id="loginButtonContainer">
                    <input type="reset" class="loginButton" value="Reset">
                    <input type="submit" class="loginButton recommended" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        <script src="validator.js">
        </script>
```

On clicking submit, it triggers the function "`validateForm()`" function, which checks to see if the username is "username" and password is "password".(It's only an experiment I'm doing, so not much security needed.) And if they're not, it adds "disabled" and "invalid" classes to the form, and then removes them. (it functions like the macOS password screen on boot up.)

Only for some reason, it only executes part of the code:

```
function validateForm() {
  var form = document.getElementById("login");
  var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
  var password = document.forms["form"]["password"].value;
    
  if (name == "username" && password == "password") {
    alert("Password is correct.");
  } else {
      alert("Password is incorrect.");


      // this part doesn't execute.
      form.classList.add("disabled");
      setTimeout(function(){
          form.classList.add("invalid");
      }, 2000);
      setTimeout(function(){
          form.classList.remove("invalid");
          form.classList.remove("disabled");
      }, 600);
  }
}
```

The part of code from `form.classList.add("disabled");` doesn't execute. Can someone help me out with this?

edit:
I tried `<div id="login" class="login">` instead of `<div id="login "class="login">`, it doesn't work.

Edit 2:
Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  font-family: system-ui;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}



.loginContainer {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         left: 0;
         background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
         z-index: 1;
}

.login {
    height: 360px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loginimage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.loginHeading {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.loginTextbox {
    height: 50px;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 20px
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.invalid {
    animation: shake .5s linear;
}

.loginTextbox:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0084FF;
  border: 1px solid #006AFF;
}

.disabled {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cccccc, #bbbbbb);
    color: gray;
}

.loginbuttonContainer{
    height: 83px;
    width: 300px;
}

.loginbutton {
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: 20px
}
.loginbutton:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.loginbutton:active {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0084FF, #006AFF);
    color: white;
}

.destructive {
    color: red;
}

.recommended {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0095FF, #007BFF);
    color: white;
}

@keyframes shake {
    8%, 41% {
           -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
           -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       25%, 58% {
           -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
           -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       75% {
           -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
           -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       92% {
           -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
           -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       0%, 100% {
           -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
           -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
}

@supports (-webkit-backdrop-filter: none) or (backdrop-filter: none) {
    .login {
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
        backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `form.classList.add()` is unknown method. You can hit keyboard key `F12` for console errors. `classList` is a readonly property. Helps to read the docs.

Comment: how about removing `alert`? it may blocks execution(I'm not sure right now)

Comment: @GetSet, I got no errors in the console.

Comment: No @Lax its because OP is calling unknown methods.

Comment: @Lax, I tried your idea, it still doesn't execute.

Comment: There is no `add` method on the property, again property, `classList`. Its reado  only

Comment: @GetSet yes, you're right

Comment: @GetSet, Are you sure? I'm  referring to [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Comment: A suggestion to reseach how to prevent form submission in JavaScript - there are multiple questions and answers on Stack Overflow and the web on the topic  Adding a `disabled` class to the form element is **not** one of them. The timeout callback will not execute before the page reloads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop reloading page after alert in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758835/how-to-stop-reloading-page-after-alert-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this here is where your problem lies

```
<div id="login "class="login">
```

There is additional " " after id="login"

And you're calling it with

```
var form = document.getElementById("login");
```

Just change

```
<div id="login "class="login">
```

to

```
<div id="login"class="login">
```

**Edit V2**

Change the following

```
setTimeout(function(){
          form.classList.remove("invalid");
          form.classList.remove("disabled");
      }, 9000); //Changes the delay of removing the effects


@keyframes shake {
    8%, 41% {
           transform: translateX(-10px);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       25%, 58% {
           transform: translateX(10px);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       75% {
           transform: translateX(-5px);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       92% {
           transform: translateX(5px);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
       0%, 100% {
           transform: translateX(0);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       }
}
```

Change from 0.5s to 2 or 3 or so, because is too instant

```
.invalid {
    animation: shake 5s linear;
}
```

Changed the color code here too

```
.disabled {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Attach your CSS files to the page as well then

Comment: Sure, I added the CSS.

Comment: Where is your class for disabled in the CSS?

Comment: here: `.disabled {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cccccc, #bbbbbb);
    color: gray;
}` Also mentioned in the post.

Comment: There's an error in your loginTextbox class too. font-size is messing a ";"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but editing the values of the css would be enough now. I suggest changing the keyframes accordingly to how you want the animation to transit from one state to another.
From the javascript part. The function is called when login button is clicked